# Recuperar mensagens Error via json no Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Estou tentando realizar um cadastro utilizando Angularjs, mas quero pegar as validações que estão no meu modelo no rails. Mas estou com dificuldades:

## Covenat(model) Rails

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

## controller Covenat Action Create

```
def create
  @covenat = Covenat.new(covenat_params)
  if @covenat.save
    render json: @covenat, status: 200
  else
    render json: { errors: @covenat.errors }, status: 422
  end
end
```

## view /assets/templates/covenats/new.html

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group" ng-class="errorClass('name')">
     <label class="control-label" for="covenat_name">Nome</label>
     <input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='covenat.name'     name='covenat_name' id="covenat_name" required/>
     <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty">
        {{ errorMessage('name')}}
     </p>
   </div>          
</form>
```

## covenats_new_controller.js

```
angular.module('clinica')
  .controller('CovenatsNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'Covenat', '$location', 
function($scope, Covenat, $location){

$scope.submit = function() {
  console.log("submit")

  function success(response) {
    console.log("success", response)
    $location.path("/covenats");
  }

  function failure(response) {
    console.log("failure", response)

    _.each(response.data, function(errors, key) {
    _.each(errors, function(e) {
      $scope.form[key].$dirty = true;
      $scope.form[key].$setValidity(e, false);
    });
   });
 }

  Covenat.save($scope.covenat, success, failure);

};

$scope.errorClass = function(name) {
 var s = $scope.form[name];
 return s.$invalid && s.$dirty ? "error" : "";
};

$scope.errorMessage = function(name) {
 var s = $scope.form[name].$error;
 result = [];
 _.each(s, function(key, value) {
   result.push(value);
 });
 return result.join(", ");
};

}]);
```

Estou com o seguinte erro na function failure:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined

na linha `return s.$invalid && s.$dirty ? "error" : "";`

Comment: Existem 2 problemas. 1. Você está tentando carregar isso: `$scope.form["name"]`e validar, experimente fazer um `console.log($scope.form["name"])` disso. 2. E não há nenhuma implementação de $invalid e $dirty neste objeto do seu código que você publicou, isso porque ele só seta parâmetros na falha da submissão... na falha vc não especificou um erro que deva ser verificado.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você chama as funções

`errorClass('name')`,
`errorMessage('name')`

você está passando como parâmetro a string "name" ou seja, quando ele chega na função.

`var s = $scope.form[name];` isso na verdade está virando `$scope.form.name` e a propriedade name não existe dentro do seu form, logo a variavel `s` está undefined, quando tenta acessar a variável $invalid mostra o erro.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é porque você está passando o parâmetro 'name' como se fosse o nome do elemento do form que queres acessar na função errorClass.

Na verdade, você deveria passar o name do atributo que queres validar a mensagem de erro, no caso 'covenat_name'.

Segue exemplo:

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group" ng-class="errorClass('covenat_name')">
     <label class="control-label" for="covenat_name">Nome</label>
     <input class='form-control' type='text' ng-model='covenat.name'     name='covenat_name' id="covenat_name" required/>
     <p class="help-block" ng-show="form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty">
        {{ errorMessage('name')}}
     </p>
   </div>          
</form>
```